# Customise main-menu link - adding a '/' between <li> items

Tags: theming, routes

I am using the [Omega HTML5 base theme](http://drupal.org/project/omega) and am attempting to add a '/' delimiter between main_menu items on my site.

I have searched high and low and the closest I've come is the following:

```
function MYTHEME_menu_link(array $variables) {
$delimiter = '';
  // Only add delimiter to the main menu
  if (strpos($variables['element']['#theme'], 'main_menu') !== FALSE ) {
    // Only add delimiter if item is not the last one
    if (!in_array('last', $variables['element']['#attributes']['class'])) {
      $delimiter = '<span class="delimiter">/</span>';
    }
  }
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  // Add delimiter just before the closing </li> tag
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . $delimiter. "</li>\n";
}
```

This actually works on any another template (just not OMEGA). Irrespective does anyone have an approach to adding this forward slash on main-menu items?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a purely CSS approach to this. There is really no need to go through the trouble of adding a function to your theme for this change.

The following CSS code would get you (at least close to) the results you desire:

```
  ul.main-menu li:after {
    content: "/";
  }
  ul.main-menu li.last:after {
    content:"";
  }
```

The `:after` [pseudo-class's support](http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/) includes all browsers except IE 7 & below and Firefox 3.0 and lower.

Comment: Completely forgot about using :after as an approach - (have been looking at this for way too long...). Thanks for putting me straight on this!

Comment: oh yeah, and then don't forget to unset that style for the last li! Edited my answer to show that :)

Comment: Actually it'd be **ul.main-menu li.last-child:after {}**
(or first-child if you wish to change the beginning)

Answer (score 0):

For those using [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), I have written a [mixin](https://gist.github.com/d4nyll/b798e0c21e8ec9af94e3) for this purpose:

```
@mixin addSeparator($element, $separator, $padding) {
    #{$element+'+'+$element}:before {
        content: $separator;
        padding: 0 $padding;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
@include addSeparator('li', '|', 1em);
```

Which will give you this:

```
li+li:before {
  content: "|";
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```